# Grouping commands inside complex bash expression

Tags: bash

I have access to a computing cluster (LSF) and the basic way to send stuff to the compute nodes is by doing:

```
bsub -I <command>
```

I had this in a file:

```
bsub -I ../configure --prefix="..." \
                     --solver=...\
                     --with-cflags=...\
        && make -j8 \
        && make install
```

However I just noticed that actually only the first command (configure) was running on the cluster, the remaining two were running locally. What's the best way to group the whole command and pass it to bsub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `bsub` you are referring to is the one documented [here](http://www.vub.ac.be/BFUCC/LSF/bsub.1.html), you have two options:

1. Surround the entire command to be executed with single quotes (assuming you don't use a single quote anywhere in the command):

   ```
   bsub -I '../configure --prefix="..."\
                         --solver=...\
                         --with-cflags=...\
           && make -j8 \
           && make install'
   ```
2. Feed the command to bsub's standard input, using a HERE document to avoid quoting issues:

   ```
   bsub -I <<END
   ../configure --prefix="..." \
                --solver=...\
                --with-cflags=...\
   && make -j8 \
   && make install
   END
   ```

Or, very similar to the second one, put the command into a file and provide the file as input.

Comment: I like the here document solution. Using single quotes and having then to worry about them inside the command, feels clumsy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
bsub -I sh -c '../configure --prefix="..." \
                     --solver=...\
                     --with-cflags=...\
        && make -j8 \
        && make install'
```